# How to initialize a constexpr struct containing arrays without using intermediate variables?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to initialize a `constexpr` struct which contains array-like fields without defining intermediate variables. Using intermediates is the only solution I could find to workaround compilation errors due to passing temporary arrays, but that pattern seems more verbose than necessary.

I'm open to using something other than `std::span` for the field member types to enable a cleaner pattern.

```
#include <span>

struct MyStruct {
    // Feel free to replace span with array, etc.
    std::span<const int> a;
    std::span<const int> b;
    // ... contains many array-like fields
};

// Would like to avoid creating these intermediate variables
constexpr std::array my_a{1,2,3};
constexpr std::array my_b{5,6};
// ...

constexpr MyStruct foo{
    .a = my_a, // Works, but requires annoying intermediate
    // .a = {1,2,3}, // Error, no matching std::span constructor
    // .a = {{1,2,3}}, // Error, creates non-constexpr temporary
    // .a = std::array{1,2,3}, // Error, creates non-constexpr temporary
    .b = my_b,
    // ...
};

constexpr MyStruct bar{
    // Will create different instances with a variety of field sizes
    //.a = {{1,2}},
    //.b = {{1,2,3,4,5}},
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your value in a template parameter:

```cpp
constexpr MyStruct foo{
  .a = std::integral_constant<std::array<int, 3>, std::array{1, 2, 3}>::value
};

// or more tersely
template<auto V>
inline constexpr auto static_storage(V);

constexpr MyStruct foo{
  .a = static_storage<std::array{1, 2, 3}>
};
```

And you can use a lambda for non-structural types:

```cpp
template<auto F>
inline constexpr auto call_static(F());

constexpr MyStruct foo{
    .a = call_static<[]{ return std::array{1, 2, 3}; }>
    .b = call_static<[]{ return std::array{5, 6}; }>
};


// In a macro if you want
#define STATIC_STORAGE(...) (call_static<[]() -> decltype(auto) { return (__VA_ARGS__) ; }>)
```

---

Since you asked in the comments, in C++17 it is quite a bit more difficult to use arrays in template arguments.

For simple types, you can use a parameter pack:

```cpp
template<auto First, decltype(First)... Rest>
inline constexpr std::array<decltype(First), sizeof...(Rest)+1u> static_array{{First, Rest...}};

// .a = static_array<1, 2, 3>
```

For more complicated types, you can still use a lambda but pass it in more creatively:

```cpp
template<typename Lambda>
struct call_static_holder {
    static_assert(std::is_empty_v<Lambda> && std::is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<Lambda>, "Lambda must be stateless");
    static constexpr Lambda lambda() {
        // No default constructor in C++17, copy all 0 members instead
        const Lambda l(l);
        return l;
    }
    static constexpr decltype(auto) value = lambda()();
};

template<typename Lambda>
constexpr auto& call_static(Lambda) {
    return call_static_holder<Lambda>::value;
}

// .a = call_static([]{ return std::array{1, 2, 3}; })
```

Comment: This works great in C++20! Out of curiosity, is there a C++17 way to do this too?

Comment: Thanks for the update! Back to C++20 (just upgraded toolchain): 
If my element type is more complex than `int`, for example `struct Inner { int x; };` yielding `struct MyStruct { std::span<const Inner> a; };` is it possible to omit the `<Inner, 1>` template arguments from `constexpr MyStruct foo{ .a = static_storage<std::array<Inner, 1>{{{.x = 1}}}> };`? Or is this asking for too much type deduction?

Comment: I could omit the count by repeating `Inner`, (e.g. `std::array{Inner{.x = 1}, Inner{.x = 2}`), but that will be pretty verbose, especially with longer struct names, and I'd rather not have to add a bunch of convenience aliases.

Comment: @MilesF You can use `static_storage< std::to_array<Inner>({ {.x = 1}, {.x = 2}, ... }) >` (Avoiding repeating `Inner` and not stating the count). I've also found that the lifetime of the array in a `std::initializer_list` is the same as the `initializer_list`, so if these are always initialized with literals, you can get away with `struct MyStruct { std::initializer_list<Inner> a; };` `constexpr MyStruct foo{ .a = { {1}, {2}, {3} } };`